# Applying custom layouts/colors to devise forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am a new bie to Rails Devise Gem. In order to apply a custom layout and coloring, I've modified original forms that come with devise installation. I am wondering if this approach is right. Or shall I create a new set of forms that should override default devise forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Then, look at devise folder at views folder, you will see all the forms you need to customize

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is to generate the devise views and then style them as you have been doing.

Comment: just incase this isn't clear, do: rails generate devise:views, reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views